# Почему 3д объект в unity имеет неправильные градусы в rotation?

Tags: unity3d, model, blender

Всем привет! Делал свою первую модель в Blender, перенес её в Unity, но возникла небольшая проблема: некоторые детали имели неправильные значения rotation. В самом Blender я применил значения rotation и они были на 0. Что может быть не так и как это можно исправить?

[image: объекты с неправильными значениями]

[image: как они выглядят на сцене]

На сцене объекты расположены так, как и должны быть. Но если я хочу приподнять руку, то оси y и z принимают значения -90.

Comment: Градус такой как есть, правильный насколько может быть. Вот только у `Blender` и `Unity` разные координатные оси и это вопрос экспорта. При экспорте ты настраиваешь что считать `Forward` и `Up` осями, `Scale` и он модифицирует модель на эти настройки. По мимо этого там есть тоггл `Apply Transform` что бы после всех модификаций, значения стали 0.

Comment: Спасибо, поставил галочку на Apply Transform и все заработало.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

При экспорте модели нужно поставить галочку на Apply Transform и тогда все заработает, как надо.